# ER model(Conceptual) to Relational(Logical) - MySqL

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

is there any way in MySQL or tool that could help me to transform a ER model to Logical model?
The ER model was done in MySQL, so if there's a way to use the file extension in another software that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench's models aren't really ER models. They're physical models consisting of tables and foreign key constraints. The entity-relationship model distinguishes between entity relations and relationship relations, but these would both be represented as tables in MySQL Workbench. Relationships in ER don't map to foreign key constraints, rather FK constraints enforce the domains of roles in relationships.

Automated translation from a physical to a logical model isn't possible, since the physical model doesn't capture domains or functional and join dependencies. ER models fare slightly better - domains are represented and some dependencies, but ER can't represent all possible relationships and constraints.